# C - How to display and delete data from a file.txt

Tags: c

In the code below I'm trying to insert, display and delete data from a file.txt. I'm being able to insert successfully but my display function do not display correct and I don't know how to set up the logic to make the delete function. I would appreciate some help in changing the code so it can works. How can I set up the logic for it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void menu() {
    printf("Option 1 - Create a file and insert data:\n");
    printf("Option 2 - Read file and display:\n");
    printf("Option 3 - Delete content:\n");
    printf("Option 4 - Exit:\n");
};

struct Book {
    char title[256];
    char author[256];
    int pages;
    int price;
};

void get() {

        struct Book *book;
        book = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));

        FILE *fPtr;

        fPtr = fopen("file.txt", "w");

        if (fPtr == NULL) {
            printf("Fail creating file");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        };


        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            printf("Enter the  book title:\n");
            scanf("%s", &book[i].title);
            fprintf(fPtr, "Title = %s", book[i].title);

            printf("Enter the author of the book:\n");
            scanf("%s", &book[i].author);
            fprintf(fPtr, "Author = %s", book[i].author);

            printf("Enter the number of pages:\n");
            scanf("%d", &book[i].pages);
            fprintf(fPtr, "Pages = %d", book[i].pages);

            printf("Enter the price:\n");
            scanf("%d", &book[i].price);
            fprintf(fPtr, "Price = %d", book[i].price);
        };

        /*for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", book[i].title);
            printf("%s\n", book[i].author);
            printf("%d\n", book[i].pages);
            printf("%d\n", book[i].price);
        };*/

        fclose(fPtr);
};

void display() {
    FILE *fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    printf("The content of file are:\n", fPtr);

    /*struct Book *book;

    book = (struct Book*)malloc(sizeof(struct Book));


    printf("%s %s %d %d", book.title, book.author, book.pages, book.price);*/

    free(book);
    fclose(fPtr);
}



int main()
{
    int opt = 0;
    int opt2 = 0;
    int var = 0;
    int validation = 0;

    while (opt != 4) {
        menu();
        do
        {
            printf("Choose an option:\n");
            validation = scanf_s("%d", &opt);
            while (getchar() != '\n');
        } while (validation != 1);

        switch (opt) {
        case 1:
            get();
            printf("Option 5 - Display data:\n");
            printf("Option 6 - Delete:\n");
            scanf("%d", &var);
            if (var == 5) {
                //FILE *fp1;
                /*fp1 = fopen("file.txt", "r");*/
                display();
            }
            else if (var == 6) {
                printf("delete!");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("First insert data:\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("First insert data:\n");
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are attempting to insert/display books, but then try to delete students. That's not an MCVE, and it's also unclear what you are asking.

Comment: The student part shouldn't be in the code, it was miss attention of mine

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to rename *Books* to *Book* because that *struct* manages one book, not several.

About the command codes to enter, rather than 1 .. 4 what about 'c' for create, 'r' for read, 'd' for delete and 'e' for exit ?

Concerning `get()` :

- you have a memory leak because the allocated Books is not freed. This allocation is useless, better to have `struct Book book;`
- `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is useless and equivalent to `int i = 0`, do you really manages only 1 book ?
- in your *fprintf* move the '\n' from the beginning to the end, else your file starts by an empty line and the last line is not ended
- Is it necessary to prefix each data by its kind like `Title =` ? To read the file content is more complex with these prefixes

Concerning `display()` :

- you do not read the content of the file, so difficult do display it :)
- you allocate a Books, do not initialize it, but write its( uninitialized) fields
- `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is useless and equivalent to `int i = 0`
- you have a memory leak because the allocated Books is not freed. This allocation is useless, better to have `struct Book book;`

Concerning `display()` :

- you do not read the content of the file, so difficult do display it :)
- you allocate a Books, do not initialize it, but write its( uninitialized) fields
- `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` is useless and equivalent to `int i = 0`
- you have a memory leak because the allocated Books is not freed. This allocation is useless, better to have `struct Book book;`

Concerning `deleteStudentRecord()` :

- `getNoOfRecords()` is not defined, but currently it must return 1 because you manage only one book in the file
- *var* is not defined, nor *ptr*
- open *file2* with "w", it is a new file
- `fread(&var, sizeof(struct student), 1, ptr)` is wrong because it supposes a line has always `sizeof(struct student)` but this is not the case refering to `get()`
- `fcloseall()` ??? just do `fclose(ptr);` and `fclose(ptr2)`, rename them fpIn and fpOut or something like will make your code more readable

Comment: If I take the loop out of the code ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) so the book.title will display an error message " expression must have struct or union type " I didn't knew how to fix it so I added.

Comment: Abou the deleteStudentRecord(); this shouldn't be in my code, it was lack of attention, I was reading other questions in the forum and trying to add and modify so I could set a logic of delete in my code.

Comment: And as I understand in the display(); when I use fp = fopen("file.txt", "r"); I'm reading it. How can I fix it? I post a new part of the code as other answer. Please take a look.

Comment: About added loop for nothing, again do not allocate Book, use a var typed struct Book

Comment: `fopen("file.txt", "r");` does not read the file, like `("file.txt", "w");` does not write its content, `fopen` just opens a file and returns a descriptor to use to read/write in it

Answer (score 1):

note : display() proposal 2

```
 void display() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

    struct Book book;


    printf("%s %s %d %d", book.title, book.author, book.pages, book.price);

    free(book);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `book` is a pointer to `struct Book`. You must access its members using the `->` arrow operator, e.g. `book->title`.

Comment: As I already said to him book has no reason at all to be a pointer nor to be allocated in the heap

Comment: book is not initialized, but you print its content, as I already said you do not read the file content currently

Comment: @bruno I used all the get(); remarks that you mentioned, just didn't change the loop yet. because I don't understand why my code breaks when I remove it.

Comment: @EdineaCarmo give your new definition of "get()" in an answer, and prefix that answer saying is "get() proposal 2"

Comment: @bruno I changed the get(); in the main answer. About the new display(); proposal, it's still not working because the variable book is not being initialized. I'm trying to figure why.

Comment: @EdineaCarmo book is not initialized because you do not initialize it, by which miracle do you imagine it is set from the content of the file ?

Comment: @EdineaCarmo it was a bad idea to change the main proposal, now it is not possible to understand the remarks nor my answer, this is why I said you to add an answer ...

Comment: @ I still can Ctr+Z and come back to the original, I'll do it. Please, I'm not being able to understand how to initialize the book. How should I do it? book = {}; ?

Answer (score 1):

"get(); proposal 2"

```
void get() {


        FILE *fPtr;

        fPtr = fopen("file.txt", "w");

        struct Book book;

        if (fPtr == NULL) {
            printf("Fail creating file");
            getch();
            exit(1);
        };

        printf("Enter the  book title:\n");
        scanf("%s", &book.title);
        fprintf(fPtr, "%s", book.title);

        printf("Enter the author of the book:\n");
        scanf("%s", &book.author);
        fprintf(fPtr, "%s", book.author);

        printf("Enter the number of pages:\n");
        scanf("%d", &book.pages);
        fprintf(fPtr, "%d", book.pages);

        printf("Enter the price:\n");
        scanf("%d", &book.price);
        fprintf(fPtr, "%d", book.price);

        /*for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", book[i].title);
            printf("%s\n", book[i].author);
            printf("%d\n", book[i].pages);
            printf("%d\n", book[i].price);
        };*/

        fclose(fPtr);
};
```

Comment: you need to put a separator between your data in the file, for instance a \n at the end of each

Comment: your scanf to read the strings are dangerous because if the input string is too long you will write the result out of the fixed length field

Comment: Do you mean just a \t as a separator?

Comment: a \t is a bad choice while you do not check that character is not into the book title nor author name, and because after that you cannot read the title/author name just reading a line, you will have to search for the \t to cut it